# Orbeon : Where are my forms

Tags: tomcat7, orbeon

I work with Orbeon Form Builder. I had created a form with the builder interface and I had published it. Now I want to find the file `myform_created_with_builderINterface.xhtml` but I don't know where the path of it to edit it.

I need this file because I would like to edit and implement some XML request and I don't know how I can proceed to make it work.

Where is the file of the form that I have created before with the builder?

Comment: BTW I marked your answer below for deletion, and copied it into a comment to my answer. StackOverflow has answers and comment, and they are different. And I followed-up in a comment to my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The published form definition is stored in a database when you save or publish it.

If you haven't made any changes to the Orbeon Forms configuration, form definitions and form data are stored into the built-in eXist database, whose files are under `WEB-INF/exist-data`.

If you have configured a relational db, form definitions and form data are stored in one of the database tables: `orbeon_form_data` for non-published form definitions and form data, and `orbeon_form_definition` for published form definitions. In both cases, look at the `xml` column.

The cross-database way of retrieving it though is to use the [persistence API](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Form-Runner-~-APIs-~-Persistence): an HTTP GET at the right URL will give you the form definition, provided the service has been [open or secured](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Controller-~-Authorization-of-Pages-and-Services).

I am still unclear why you need this "to edit and implement some XML request" though. Better work with the source of the form definition, which you can see in Form Builder's Edit Source, or using [custom model logic](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Form-Runner-~-Custom-Model-Logic).

Comment: Copying Loïc's comment here as it's not an answer: "Thank you for your answer. Indeed, I have my form (DisplayNameForms) in one part and in another part an XML file with different name (Name.XML). I would like that when I click in the button display in my forms (DisplayNameForms) that appear all the name on the XML file (Name.XML). How I can proceed ? I would like to use javascript or other but I don't know how to make it work."

Comment: It's hard to tell you how to do it without seeing some code. In general, you wouldn't refer to an XML file from Form Builder. Are you using this as a placeholder for a service call?